# I cant get my code to check if a number is already in a array | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

```
var usedNumbers = []
var counter = 0

while(counter < 9){
    var math = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)
    
    if(math != usedNumbers){
        usedNumbers[counter] = math
        counter++
    }
}

console.log(usedNumbers)
```

i am really bad at explaining and really new to coding but i will do my best

i want my piece of code to create a random number, check if that number is used before and then put it in the array so i can use it later.
but for some reason the if statement is always true so it doesnt check for duplicates

if someone can explain what i did wrong and how to fix it that would be great

Comment: used numbers is an array you should check if it includes the value already

Comment: `math != usedNumbers` is checking to see if a number doesn't equal an array. You need to check to see if a number is not inside of the array... `!usedNumbers.includes(math)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the array method [.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var usedNumbers = []
var counter = 0

while(counter < 9){
    var math = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)
    
    if(!usedNumbers.includes(math)){
        usedNumbers[counter] = math
        counter++
    }
}

console.log(usedNumbers.sort())
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and check only the `size` of it.

```js
const numbers = new Set;

while (numbers.size < 9) numbers.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9));

console.log(...numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional and recursive way of doing it.

```
const saveNums = (currentNum, size, result) => {
  if (result.length >= size) {
    return result;
  }
  const newResult = result.includes(currentNum) ? result : [...result, currentNum]; 
  return saveNums(Math.floor(Math.random() * size), size, newResult);
};

console.log(saveNums(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9), 9, []));
```